# Is it okay to display records in a table with broken ID because of delete

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have searched everywhere and couldn't find the answer. What is the standard in displaying a records from database in front end? For example, I want to display records from a table in database but some of its records are already deleted and now it will show in the backend or in admin with broken count of id such as

1
2
4
5
6

Is it okay display it like this?

Comment: You show ID of record, not sequence of record, so it should be _ok_. Same as if you would show phone numbers not including all other possible numbers in between (here it's illogical, right?)

Comment: Well yes, but it depends on what you want. Normally you 'soft-delete' records so they're excluded from the query. Also what is the benefit of showing the record id's on the front-end?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It kinda depends on what the client want, but in general:

- the deleted records are just left out from the listing on data (of which the ID might be part of)
- usually you do not actually physically remove the entry, but instead set "deleted" status and exclude them in SQL query
- when you are listing entries like invoices, you often do not have the ID matching the invoice number, since those invoice numbers will probably have their own business-rules for generating them

Answer (score -1):

don't show its id's from database rather show its id index (which always start from 0) then make it increment by 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).